# Chromecast warning loadMedia autoplay is deprecated

Tags: ios, chromecast

On my playSelectedItemRemotely method I get a warning message:

```
 - (void)playSelectedItemRemotely {
    GCKCastSession* castSession = [GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager.currentCastSession;
    if (castSession) {
        // WARNING ON LINE BELOW
        [castSession.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:[self buildMediaInformation] autoplay:YES]; 
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No cast session!");
    }
}
```

says:

> 'loadMedia:autoplay:' is deprecated: Use loadMedia:withOptions:

how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Like warning message said, you can use loadMedia:withOptions method like below:

```
- (void)playSelectedItemRemotely {
    GCKCastSession* castSession = [GCKCastContext sharedInstance].sessionManager.currentCastSession;
    if (castSession) {
        GCKMediaLoadOptions *options = [GCKMediaLoadOptions init];
        [castSession.remoteMediaClient loadMedia:[self buildMediaInformation] withOptions:options];
    } else {
        BILog(@"No cast session!");
    }
}
```

here are the options that you can use:

> - (BOOL) autoplay Whether playback should start immediately.
>
> The default value is YES.
>
> - (NSTimeInterval) playPosition The initial playback position.
>
> The default value is kGCKInvalidTimeInterval, which indicates a
>   default playback position.
>
> - (float) playbackRate The playback rate.
>
> The default value is 1.
>
> - (NSArray*) activeTrackIDs An array of integers specifying the active tracks.
>
> The default value is nil.
>
> - (id) customData Custom application-specific data to pass along with the request.
>
> Must either be an object that can be serialized to JSON using
>   NSJSONSerialization, or nil.
>
> - (NSString*) credentials
>
> The user credentials for the media item being loaded.
>
> - (NSString*) credentialsType
>
> The type of user credentials specified in
>   GCKMediaLoadOptions::credentials.

please also check [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_load_options#a4f298b6f00702a98619ef19cc22feb3f).